# Eigen array shift gives strange result

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm almost sure it's a trivial problem, but I can't understand what wrong is going on.
I have a simple array in `Eigen` that I need to right-shift, so that I can always insert new sample at position 0:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;
typedef VectorXd vec;

// The actual buffer
int N = 10;
vec _x(N);
_x = vec::Constant(0.0);

// This is just for dimonstrative purpose
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    _x(seq(1, N - 1)) = _x(seq(0, N - 2));
    _x(0) = (double) i;
}
```

What I got is that, at each cycle, it is copying twice each element to be shifted:

```
--- After cycle 1: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
--- After cycle 2: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
--- After cycle 3: [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
--- After cycle 4: [3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
--- ...
--- After cycle 10: [9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4]
```

I'm pretty sure I'm messing something around with Eigen. What's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

As you found out yourself, you have an aliasing problem -- which can be solved by adding an `eval()` at the end of the expression. However, this (usually) requires an extra memory allocation. If you want to move the elements in-place, you can use `std::copy_backward`:

```
std::copy_backward(_x.begin(), _x.end()-1, _x.end());
```

But this is also not optimal, since it likely does not vectorize well.

---

The actual solution to your problem should be to re-think how you can collect your data without always having to copy everything.

For example, have a bigger array which you start filling backwards from position `end()-10`, and always just use a `.segment()` of that array.

If you only rarely need to actually use the array, use some kind of ring-buffer which you only copy to an Eigen structure when needed.

Answer (score 1):

It was tricky and trivial at the same time. The problem is into the [`aliasing`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html) that Eigen vectors undergo when performing block assignment.

The solution is to compute `.eval()` at the right-hand operator in order to let Eigen evaluate the new array first, and only then assign it to the left-hand block:

```
_x(seq(1, N - 1)) = _x(seq(0, N - 2)).eval();
```

Hope this can be useful for someone

Answer (score 0):

First, as other say, aliasing is the problem, don't get caught in the "easy syntax" of the library.
Expression templates can lead to bad code.
Also mutation and aliasing are incompatible.

My solution would be to forget about this feature and go back to the basics of algorithms.
If you want to shift elements, well `std::shift_` the elements then:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace Eigen;
    typedef VectorXd vec;

    // The actual buffer
    int N = 10;
    vec _x(N);

    // This is just for dimonstrative purpose
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    //    _x(seq(1, N - 1)) = _x(seq(0, N - 2));
        std::shift_right(_x.begin(), _x.end(), 1);
        _x(0) = static_cast<double>(i);

        std::cout << '[' << _x << ']' << std::endl;
    }

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rnhsPxdsE

more idiomatic:

```
    for(int i = 0; i != N; i++) {
        *(std::shift_right(_x.begin(), _x.end(), 1) - 1) = static_cast<double>(i);
    }
```

Comment: Code sorted out. Should compile now, otherwise, please spot the exception. I'm not sure why expression templates could lead to bad code. Could you explain it better?

Comment: ok. what exception? expression templates makes gives you a false sense of security that any expression that you can possibly write is 1) valid, 2) efficient. Both are in general false, even when they can be correct, efficiency is extremely difficult to implement right. If you are going to hatch-escape all the time doing `.eval()` then why use ET at all? With ET you quickly loose track of what is going on and end up evaluating everything just in case. This has been the holy grail of "formula" based languages since the times of Backus (Fortran), there was never a satisfactory solution.